# Azure SQL DB Distribution Count

Tags: azure, data-warehouse, azure-synapse

Can the distribution count of Azure SQL Datawarehouse be changed?

It is currently defaulted to 60 and I have not figured out how to change it.

Answer (score 3):

No. The number of distributions is an internal mechanism for how data within tables is spread across the compute infrastructure. A user can choose the type of distribution model (Round Robin vs. Hash distributed) for the data being split but the actual management of the distributions is handled for the user. This simplifies the management of data and tables by not requiring a user to understand and optimize the distributions.

To optimize the service, you can change the amount of compute power measured in Data Warehouse Units (DWU) simply by moving a slider. This allows the data split in the distributions to be executed over by more or less compute power - enabling massive scale.

See the Azure SQL DW Table documentation at:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-data-warehouse-develop-table-design/

Answer (score 1):

This value is related to the underlying infrastructure and not a configuration option you can choose. In APS' PDW, it would be a function of the amount of hardware you had, being eight times the number of compute nodes involved, but with the cloud offering you have even less control over it.

Embrace the value of 60, and work on minimising data movement to let your queries work fast.